# Displaying dirsize in batch file windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, directory, batch-file, batch

I'm trying to display the dirsize with a batch file but so far no luck. DU, dirsize gives me a not recognized as an internal or external command error.

This is my batch file so far, it displays all the dir's but not the size.

```
dir D:\test\test2
PAUSE
```

Are there more commands to display dirsize?

Thanks

Comment: If you haven't found how to achieve what you're asking, take a look at the answer given on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813826/get-folder-size-from-windows-command-line)

Answer (score -1):

You're right, after some researches I found this command :

```
C:\Users\TEMP>dir "C:\Users\TEMP\Desktop" | find "(s)"
           1 fichier(s)            2'253 octets
           2 Rép(s)  18'042'929'152 octets libres
```

Comment: The problem here is that it goes deeper then the level required, I have test1/test2/test3, I only need the dirs in test 2.

Comment: Why are you still using batch files on server 2012?

Comment: Why is that comment usefull? When someone wants to use batch files they use batch files ... Not helping to find a solution